# DRF Browsable API only shows one Router

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-urls, python-3.4

Essentially, depending on the order in which I add my routes to my `urlpatterns` the browsable API will only show one router at a time. Here's my code:

urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from rest_framework import routers

from .views import PlantViewSet

# url router
router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'plants', PlantViewSet, base_name='Plants')

djoser_urls = [url(r'^', include('djoser.urls')), ]

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^api-auth/', include('rest_framework.urls', namespace='rest_framework')),
    url(r'^docs/', include('rest_framework_swagger.urls')),
    # url(r'^', include(router.urls)),
    # url(r'^', include('djoser.urls')),
] + djoser_urls + router.urls
```

This only displays the `djoser` urls:

[image: djoser_only]

However simply reversing the order in which I add the urls:

urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from rest_framework import routers

from .views import PlantViewSet

# url router
router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'plants', PlantViewSet, base_name='Plants')

djoser_urls = [url(r'^', include('djoser.urls')), ]

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^api-auth/', include('rest_framework.urls', namespace='rest_framework')),
    url(r'^docs/', include('rest_framework_swagger.urls')),
    # url(r'^', include(router.urls)),
    # url(r'^', include('djoser.urls')),
] + router.urls + djoser_urls
```

This only displays the `router` urls!

[image: router_only]

The same thing happens when I just use the `include()` lines I've commented out, whichever comes first in the list is the only router that gets displayed. Furthermore, no matter which router gets picked up the `api-auth/` and `docs/` urls are never shown. Is there anyway to get a unified api root without having to create my own custom view?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This doesn't have anything to do with Django REST framework, it happens because of how Django deals with duplicate urls.

You are trying to have a single url be handled by two different views: The DRF router index and the djoser root view. Django will only display the first view matching the search pattern that it finds, which is generally the first urls that are included in the url patterns.

Django REST framework will also not detect multiple routers that are available and group them together on the same page, which is sounds like you are hoping to see. Even if it could, [djoser doesn't use a router](https://github.com/sunscrapers/djoser/blob/fe1b8e8e341c80805c17bd138c5da7828ea90d25/djoser/views.py#L12-L33) so there is no way that DRF could actually know to include it.

> Is there anyway to get a unified api root without having to create my own custom view?

So to answer the main question: No it is not possible for Django REST framework to automatically group these views together. You are going to need to create your own customer view to handle this.